# How can I mimic Python's step argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, slice

In Python, I can overwrite elements in an array using slicing syntax and passing a step argument.
For example:

```
alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
alist[::2] = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"]
print(alist) # ['foo', 2, 'foo', 4, 'foo', 6, 'foo', 8, 'foo', 10]
```

Is there a way to mimic this behavior in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and return an element from the second list on every even iteration.

```js
const alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const blist = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"];
const clist = alist.map((e,i) => i%2==0?blist[i/2]:e);

console.log (clist)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement such a function yourself with a `for` loop.

```js
var alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var alist2 = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"]
function overwrite(arr, arr2, step){
  for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length && j < arr2.length; i += step, j++){
    arr[i] = arr2[j];
  }
}
overwrite(alist, alist2, 2);
console.log(alist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know  if this works for you:

```js
function range(from, to){
  let f = from, t = to;
  if(t === undefined){
    t = from; f = 0;
  }
  for(var i=f,r=[]; i<=t; i++){
    r.push(i);
  }
  return r;
}
function step(a, num, b){
  const r = b.slice();
  for(let i=num-1,l=a.length; i<l; i+=num){
    if(!a.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      break;
    }
    r.splice(i, 0, a[i]);
  }
  return r;
}
const aList = range(1, 10), bList = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'];
console.log(step(aList, 2, bList)); console.log(step(aList, 3, bList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this with a `for..of` loop. If you like, you could even define it as a method on `Array.prototype`, with a signature that looks a bit like the one of `splice`:

```js
Array.prototype.stepAssign = function (start, step, ...values) {
    for (const value of values) {
        this[start] = value;
        start += step;
    }
}
// Example use:
const alist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const alist2 = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"];
alist.stepAssign(0, 2, ...alist2);
console.log(alist);
```

In line with JavaScript's support for *sparse* arrays, this allows to step beyond the original length of the target array, and so there is no need for an `end` argument -- that end is completely determined by the number of values that are provided.